# ansible block of code

Tags: ansible

I need to create an xml formated file in ansible.  The file contains <> and spaces.

When I run the playbook without the <>  or any white spaces between lines in it, the playbook creates the files.

How can I create a file with the following context

```
blockinfile:
  path: /tmp/testfile.txt
  content: |
          <example1>
            this is test1
            blah
            blah
          </example1>

         <example2>
          this is test2
          hello
         </example2>
```

Comment: Did Lewis' post answer your question? If so, mark the answer as "accepted" by klicking the check mark sign to the left of the answer!

Answer (score 2):

Look at the block section of blockinfile, https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/modules/blockinfile_module.html

Here is an example role

```
user1$ cat testblock/tasks/main.yml
---
- name: Testing blockinfile
  blockinfile:
    path: /tmp/testfile.txt
    block: |
      <example1>
         this is a test1
         blah
         blah
       </example1>

       <example2>
         this is test2
         hello
       </example2>
...
```

And here is the playbook:

```
user1$ cat testblock.yml
---
- hosts: localhost
  roles:
    - testblock
...
```

Running `ansible-playbook ./testblock.yml` produces the following file:

```
user1$ cat /tmp/testfile.txt
# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
<example1>
   this is a test1
   blah
   blah
 </example1>

 <example2>
   this is test2
   hello
 </example2>
# END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
```